# Formatting list row based on status column Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, formatting

I am trying to change the background color of each row in SharePoint list on office 365. I have been looking online for two days there are so many solutions and most of them don't work on new list experience.
My main objective to conditional format a row based on a value of a status column.
can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible**.

You can use **View Formatting** in Office 365 to color the rows based on the Status field.

Use below JSON code to color the rows in your list:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Done', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status] == 'In progress', 'sp-field-severity--low' ,if([$Status] == 'In review','sp-field-severity--warning', if([$Status] == 'Has issues','sp-field-severity--blocked', ''))))"
}
```

You can put above code by selecting **Format current view** option as given below:

[image]

**Reference**:
1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting).

**Update**:

To use customized colors and formatting you need to use `rowFormatter` in JSON formatting:

You can find view samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples).

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear with my question. I need specific color not predefined color . is this possible?

Comment: Which colors do you want?

Comment: in this case, you need to use `rowFormatter`. check updated answer.

Comment: I need to do this for several lists. I need to have at least 20 different colors.

Comment: You need to add the json code in each list separately.